# How to add a label to the max value in R's ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

how can I add a label to the max value of this plot:

```
qplot(c, data=subset(df,c < 3000),geom="freqpoly")
```

[image]

c is just integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think either `annotate` or `geom_text` is what you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409357/how-to-nicely-annotate-a-ggplot2-manual